# ddply error when the aggregation function is defined within another function

Tags: r, plyr

The point of the following almost minimal code is the application of ddply within a function f where the aggregation function (helper) of ddply is self-defined within the definition of f.

Unfortunately, i don't understand why sourcing the entire snippet produces an
*Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "helper"*. The code works when the helper function is run independently of the function f. When i replace the **ddply** call with the uncommented call of **by**, the code runs without error.

Can you explain the error and provide a solution or a workaround? [Tested with plyr 1.8.1 and R 3.0.3]

```
rm (list = ls())
library(plyr)

f <- function() {

  dfx <- data.frame(
    group = c(rep('A', 8), rep('B', 15), rep('C', 6)),
    sex = sample(c("M", "F"), size = 29, replace = TRUE),
    age = runif(n = 29, min = 18, max = 54)
  )

  helper <- function(x) {
    return(max(x))
  }

  result <- ddply(dfx, .(group, sex), summarize, max_age = helper(age))
  #result <- by(dfx$age, dfx[,c("group", "sex")], helper)

  return(result)
}

print(f())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
result <- ddply(dfx, .(group, sex), here(summarize), max_age = helper(age))
```

From the help page for `here`:

> This function captures the current context, making it easier to use **ply with functions that do special evaluation and need access to the environment where ddply was called from.

`summarize` is one such special function.

Comment: Excellent, that works perfectly! Thanks a lot for the quick answer. With hindsight, i guess that "here" was added to plyr exactly for this kind of environment issue.